# Is it safe to change a HashMap key/value during iteration?

Tags: java

I have a HashMap. I loop through the map like this:

```
Map<Long, Integer> map = new HashMap<Long, Integer>();
for (Long key : map.keySet() ) {
   int value = map.get(key);
   value--;
   map.put(key, value);
}
```

Is the way I'm using to update the map safe? Safe in the sense that it doesn't damage the map because of the iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is perfectly safe operation that you're doing  since you're just changing value of an existing key in the Map.

However if you are ever going to delete an entry from Map then remeber to use Iterator.

Answer (score 9):

You could consider writing your code more efficiently as:

```
Map<Long, Integer> map = new HashMap<Long, Integer>();
for (Entry<Long, Integer> entry : map.entrySet() ) {
    entry.setValue(entry.getValue() - 1);
}
```

This is a micro-optimization, but sometimes it matters, and you don't lose anything.  It's shorter and clears up any ambiguity about the safety to boot!

Comment: this is too much code, I dunno but I find it ugly :/

Answer (score 8):

As you can see in the [HashMap source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#line-385), the `put` method only modifies the `modCount` when a new key is provided. `modCount` is used by the iterator to check for changes, and if such a change occurred between two calls to an iterator's `next()`, a `ConcurrentModificationException` would be thrown. This means that the way you are using `put` is **safe**.